# wget error when trying to download files

Tags: powershell, web, wget

I am trying to download files from a website using **wget**, I tried this command I found online:

```
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off https://website.name/mydownloads.php
```

I started [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) in one of my folders and used the command there but it returns:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "-t1" value of type "System.String" to type "Sy
stem.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:13
+ wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off https://website.na ...
+             ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Is this because I did not install **wget** correctly or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Use `wget.exe` - otherwise you are calling PowerShells Invoke-Webrequest (as it says in your error message). Search SO for the reason why. It has been answered dozens of times.

Comment: From where do I start PowerShell? It can not find wget.exe but I wouldn't know where that would be located on my pc @Swonkie

Comment: `wget.exe` is a 3rd party application. It is ubiquitous on Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

The command you have given is a wget.exe command not a PowerShell 'wget' command.

PowerShell defines an aliase wget for Invoke-WebRequest, so if you have wget.exe on your system you will still need to type either the path OR at least the .exe extension to bypass the alias:

```
wget.exe -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off https://website.name/mydownloads.php
```

OR

```
C:\PathTOwget\wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off https://website.name/mydownloads.php
```

You can obtain Gnu wget.exe for Windows here:

```
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
```

You can tell this is a wget.exe example most easily by the large number of single letter switches but most definitively by the switch with =off and the run together .zip switch which PowerShell doesn't use (also for me, years of using the wget.exe program).

Alternatively you can attempt to convert this to a PowerShell invoke-webrequest but several of those switches have no direct analog in Invoke-WebRequest.